# Why does BlueJ say that modulo isn't a statement?

Tags: modulo, bluej

For school I have to make a little program that makes Ticket Id's. One task says: "***The ticket ID is the age modulo the length of the first name + the length of the last name***. I've tried this:

```
TicketID = firstname + lastname;

TicketID.length() % age;
```

I get the error that the % is not a statement.

If you could help me that would be amazing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the result of % to some other variable

```
TicketID = firstname + lastname;

(here) = TicketID.length() % age;
```